# Price doesn't revert after catalog price rule goes inactive

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, catalog-price-rules

I set a catalog price rule for a category that had two products in it. Each of those products was also in other categories not part the catalog price rule. I've now inactivated the catalog price rule, removed the products from the category that had the catalog price rule and have reindexed and flushed cache. But the prices of these products in the other categories remains discounted. It's stuck!

Comment: do you use any full page cache? and please check if your reindexing process really worked

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to his "save and apply" instead of save when making the catalog price rule inactive.  Thank you for your help.